# How can I record from do multi iPhone cameras

Tags: software-recommendation, software, mac, multi-camera, iphone

I’ve been asked to provide a cost effective solution for recording a church service. I need to use three cameras in three different locations. There is a Mac onsite that I will be recording to. I need to be able to switch between the cameras. It won’t be broadcast live but uploaded to the web shortly after the service. There won’t be time to edit three separate recordings hence the need to switch between the cameras. The other constraint is the cameras need to small and it’s likely I can’t run cables. So I was thinking there maybe an iOS app that produces a stream I can connect to and some software on the Mac that can record and switch between the streams.

I’m new to this so appreciate alternative solutions. I can get three phones together and we have the Mac so hopefully just an app software solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing free, i can't suggest you purchase anything to fit your scenario; nonetheless i suggest you take a look of [How to Use Your iPhone as a Webcam for OBS Live Streaming (Not Free Anymore)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRDPlZ0YZjI) and Google OBS